# PHP + AJAX login page: login is needed twice on mobile devices

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm new to programming, and I've created a simple login page - below is the stripped down version without security measures.

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login">
```

The data is handled through AJAX:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    data: $( this ).serialize(),
    url: 'login.php'
} )

.done( function( data ) {
    if( data == 'login' ) {
        location = 'main/'
    }
} )
```

Which sends it to a PHP script (`login.php`). After validating the credentials a cookie is set:

```
setcookie( 'my_login_page', '12345678', time() + ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 ), '/' );

echo 'login';
```

It works perfectly, but after a while I noticed you have to login twice on mobile devices. The cookie 'disappears'. When you login again, it sticks. For weeks I've been trying to track down the cause, linked an iPhone to Safari for inspection, tried several different approaches for the redirection and more. For example `location.reload( true );` instead of redirecting and redirecting with PHP if a cookie was set. Nothing seems to work and I can't find an issue on here that's exactly similar.

Can someone help me out? Maybe this isn't even the right approach for such a login, echoing 'login' feels awkward for example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're setting the cookie in the page being called by ajax?

Comment: No, it's being set in a different PHP file. I thought it wouldn't mind since the cookie is for the whole domain (`'/'`).

Comment: Then your question makes no sense because it doesn't include any truly relevant code.  But I think I'd ditch the cookie idea and just use session, and let it expire normally. There's no good reason to use a cookie to log someone in for a whole year anyway.

Comment: Which code should I add to clarify? I was using sessions before, but kept being logged out after a short while. A year is a lot indeed and could be less, but I just want to stay logged in all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the cookie is disappearing? It sounds like what's happening is mobile safari is refreshing before PHP finishes setting the cookie, so it's not getting the cookie in the header until the next request. What happens when you login once with mobile and then refresh the page?

Comment: That could be it, when I refresh I'm redirected back to the login page. Is it a good idea to add a small `setTimeout` to the redirect?

Comment: You could try it... When you inspect your cookies after refresh, does the cookie appear? If not, then that's not the issue.